# Using a related entry inside a reverse related entry?

Tags: related-entries, reverse-related-entries

I have a channel 'user' with a detail page about them.

I then use a

`{reverse_related_entries channel="post"}` tag to pull in entries that user created and list them on that page. This all works great.

The entry in the post channel also has a related entry, so I am trying to call it but am not having any luck. Can I call a related entry inside a reverse related entry?

Heres an example with just EE tags:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="user"}
    {title} 
    {reverse_related_entries channel="posts"}
        {title}
        {related_entries id="myfield"}
            {title}
        {/related_entries}
    {/reverse_related_entries}  
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

but the nested related entry returns `{REL[myfield]UyOu51DdREL}`.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done natively using an embedded template.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="user"}
    {title}
    {reverse_related_entries channel="posts"}
        {embed="_embeds/related" entry_id="{entry_id}"}    
    {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in your embed (**_embeds/related**):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
    {title}
    {related_entries id="myfield"}{title}{/related_entries} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do it natively but you can using the third party add-on [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) and the `var_prefix` option.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="user"}
    {title}
    {exp:playa:children channel="posts" parse="inward" var_prefix="post"}
        {exp:playa:children channel="editors" var_prefix="editor"}
            {post:title} - {editor:title}
        {/exp:playa:children}
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You would replace `channel="editors"` with the name of the related channel and set a `var_prefix` name that suited.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I was able to do it with an embed, though I'm sure playa would have been good as well.